# Reformatting table in Excel - Can PivotTables cut it?

Tags: microsoft-excel, database, pivot-table

Suppose I have a table in an Excel worksheet which looks like this:

| Day | TimeOfDay | Color | Foo |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Morning | Green | 450 |
| 1 | Morning | Blue | 682 |
| 1 | Evening | Green | 253 |
| 1 | Evening | Blue | 413 |
| 2 | Morning | Green | 150 |
| 2 | Morning | Blue | 282 |
| 2 | Evening | Green | 453 |
| 2 | Evening | Blue | 513 |

etc.; and there are only three possible colors. This table could be rearranged with columns:

| Day | TimeOfDay | GreenFoo | BlueFoo |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Morning | 450 | 682 |
| etc. | etc. | etc. | etc. |

... and I would like to do that in Excel.

I can use the PivotTable feature, with Day and TimeOfDay as the row fields, Color as a column field, and (average of) Foo for the value field. And - removing all totals and grand totals. Doing that, I get:

[image]

... but that combines "Day" and "TimeOfDay" into a single column, while I want them in separate columns. I eventually want just the plain rearranged table.

How can I (most easily) achieve that in Excel? Naturally I'm not 'married' to PivotTables, that was just the closest I got.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are already on a good track with a Pivot Table. To achieve what you want, you need to go based on the Pivot table that you already have to `Design` -> `Report Layout` -> `Show in Tabular Form` and `Repeat All Item Labels`.

The result will look as follows:

[image: Result]